# Warp filter on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I am trying to create a warp filter in objective c, just like [this one](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/WarpFilter.html) in java. I'm having a hard time with it. Anyone could help me with some ideas how to begin in general? The answer is not expected to be iOS specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to check out the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) for iOS and OS X. Using Core Image is really the easiest way to apply filters on iOS. Here you'll find all the information on how to use Apple's filters and how to write your own. In the [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346), also check out CIParallelogramTile. If you have a Mac version of your app, this filter might be a good option to explore. This particular filter is not supported on iOS, but many other similar ones are available in the CI Programming Guide.

Comment: bicska88 - this answer help you? CIParallelogramTile - now is available Mac OS platform only. Can you describe me, what is you choice for this effect? (i mean framework or library)

Answer (score 0):

Core Image does not provide the ability to support **Warp filter** for iOS platform. This features is available for Mac OS platform only.